# How to Call webservice from contoller in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, jquery-mobile

I badly need your help. I need to bind xml to grid in mvc4 using jquery mobile. i got xml through web service in controller but no idea how to make the xml content to grid and whether i need to pass the xml content to model ? I searched in net but didnt get clear example.

Comment: first you parse the xml to objects and then use the objects as your model and pass in the views.

Comment: Here's an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381544/jquery-mobile-xml-parsing-into-table

Answer (score 0):

If this is a ajax called request, you can return back the xml as response of request and use an API to parse XML via Javascript. With that, you deserialize the xml just one time. If you parse to object and return model, you will deserialize two times.

Consider use: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/